# Lost front end back templates after updating 1.9.3.6 to 1.9.6.8?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, product-images, upgrade, magento-1.9.3.6

After updating from `1.9.3.6` to `1.9.6.8` the front and backend templates are gone. Also none of the product **images** are being shown. What could be the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: This can happen if you don't respected the Magento Standards durring development, exemple: to don't update the `Magento core files`, create your own theme instead of updating the `base` one. and also maybe some modules installed are not compatible with this version.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade Magento version, you can face many issues like below

1.It will create maintenance flag to the site root. Need to delete it.

2.sometime Folder permission goes wrong. Make Right permission if you are on the live site. (Make outer root permission 755 & var, media 777 permission needed. Check .htaccess permission(644) )

3.Create PHP version issue as we know that type-casting is available in php7.